# Blank QQuickWidget

Tags: qt, qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs

import QtQuick.Scene3D

import Qt3D.Core
import Qt3D.Render
import Qt3D.Input
import Qt3D.Extras

Rectangle {
   visible:true
   anchors.fill:parent
   property string _fileName:"C:/3DSCAN/3DSCAN/3DSCAN/testobject.obj"

    DropArea{
        id:dropArea;
        anchors.fill:parent
        onEntered:(drag)=>{
            drag.accept (Qt.linkAction);
        }
        onDropped:(drop)=>{
            _fileName:drop.text
        }
    }
    Scene3D{
        anchors.fill:parent
        id:modelscene
        aspects:["input","logic"]
        cameraAspectRatioMode: Scene3D.AutomaticAspectRatio
            Entity{
                id:sceneRoot
                    Camera{
                        id:camera
                        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                        fieldOfView: 30
                        aspectRatio:16/9
                        nearPlane:0.1
                        farPlane:1000.0
                        position:Qt.vector3d(10.0,0.0,0.0)
                        upVector:Qt.vector3d(0.0,1.0,0.0)
                        viewCenter:Qt.vector3d(0.0,0.0,0.0)
                    }
                    OrbitCameraController{
                        camera:camera
                    }
                    components: [
                        RenderSettings{
                            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer{
                                clearColor: Qt.rgba(0,0.5,1,1)
                                camera:camera
                            }
                        },
                        InputSettings{

                        }
                    ]
                    Entity{
                         id:monkeyEntity
                         components:
                         SceneLoader{
                             id:sceneLoader
                             source: _fileName
                         }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I work with visual studio not Qt Creator.
I was trying to read an .obj file and render it in a 3DSCENE where I could drag and rotate the object.
I was trying to run this qml in a `QQuickWidget` which I added to my `QGrahpicsScene` but All I see is a blank `QQuickWidget` in the middle of my `QGraphicsScene`.

I tried compiling my code with a different qml that I wrote and it worked so the problem is about rendering it I suppose.

Comment: Please avoid asking for "help asap", it will not get your question answered any faster than without it (on the contrary, it's considered annoying: this is not a help desk nor a paid service, some questions get answers even **years** after being asked). See [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: Why is QGraphicsScene necessary? QML offers the same advantages and logic as the Qt Graphics Framework. QML uses opengl or similar which are not handled by QGraphiscScene.

Comment: its not up to me to just use qml I have to use it that way but I dont know why its not working because its suppose to work

Comment: You seem to mix Qt3d with QtQuick3d, those are 2 different APIs in Qt for 3d display